# Where the values in the sessions are saved

Tags: php

```
 $_session['user_id']=4;
```

Where this values of session is saved.. means in some file??
where??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are stored in a temporary file somewhere on the server your website resides on. You can specify that setting in **php.ini** with `session.save_path`.

You could also use the function `session_save_path` to set and get session path from your script.

**Syntax:**

```
string session_save_path ([ string $path ] )
```

`session_save_path` — Get and/or set the current session save path

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it in a temp file in `session.save_path`, whatever that is set to?

You might also find the answer you want in more detail [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path).

Answer (score 0):

By default I think php stores its session information on the server, although you can override this to store session information in cookies on the client side.

Comment: And yes, I believe this information is stored in a file on the server using a generated alphanumeric string as it's name. (this is the PHPSESSID, and you can choose where the file is stored using the session_save_path method)

Comment: @Crozin: I didn't say it was a good idea, I just said it was possible. :)

Answer (score 0):

PHP saves sessions in files. The location of these files is determined in `php.ini` by the `session.save_path` setting.